Bug in LEGO® Answers Badges
I have noticed this bug in 
LEGO® Answers where my badges don't show in the list of Accounts I have in StackOverflow and other StackExchange Accounts. I have earned about 8 badges and none show up.   


Edit: The "Badge Bug" has been fixed.


Curious - they are appearing on your overall Network profile:

Could possibly be a slight caching issue - when did you earn those badges? If it's fairly recently that might explain it.
If it's not cleared up in a couple of hours I guess we should escalate it further.
Following it further, I can see that your Ask Different badge count has increased across the network (it's now 3) - I've raised this on meta.SO, it may be closed as a duplicate.
Looks like there's a more systemic issue - I've just noticed that a lot of our users are missing a large number of badges in the summary.

Edit to add:
It's been fixed, thanks for raising it :-) 

Thanks for your Post. I hope StackExchange fixes it soon..

Lego is the only Account with Issue.

Almost - it seems to be happening across all sites with a ® in their name - so ExpressionEngine® Answers users are also seeing it.

When do you think the issue will be resolved?

Not sure, I'll see if I can ping a dev for their take on it...

Thanks the "Badge Bug" is fixed. Thanks for your Help :)

Could you add the Status-Completed tag to my Question :)

Doh, knew there was some thing I'd forgotten ;)

Thanks for all your Help :)
